# Accessing Textbox within in a Group

Tags: reporting-services

I know this has to have been asked before, but I lack the vocabulary to even form the query.  If someone could direct me in the appropriate direction, it would be much appreciated.

I have a relatively simple SSRS Matrix.

I am returning ten years worth of data, grouping on Location in the RowGroup, and Year in ColumnGroup

```
-----------------------
|      |      |  YEAR |
-----------------------
| TYPE | NAME |  Count|  <<==  ReportItems!Textbox1
-----------------------
```

This would be sample data to feed my report:

```
------------------------------
|Type|Name    |Year   |Count |
------------------------------
| 1  |Bob's   |2007   |4126  |
-----------------------------|
| 1  |Bob's   |2008   |4031  |
-----------------------------|
| 1  |Bob's   |2009   |4268  |
-----------------------------|
| 1  |Bob's   |2010   |4504  |
-----------------------------|
| 1  |Bob's   |2011   |4605  |
-----------------------------|
| 1  |Bob's   |2012   |4888  |
-----------------------------|
| 1  |Bob's   |2013   |4761  |
-----------------------------|
| 1  |Bob's   |2014   |4689  |
-----------------------------|
| 1  |Bob's   |2015   |4573  |
-----------------------------|
| 1  |Bob's   |2016   |4388  |
-----------------------------|
| 1  |Bob's   |2017   |4702  |
------------------------------
```

The result is similar to this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
|    |       | 2007 | 2008 | 2009 | 2010 | 2011 | 2012 | 2013 | 2014 | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 | 1 year change| 3 year change| 5 year change| 10 year change|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
| 1  | Bob's | 4126 | 4031 | 4268 | 4504 | 4605 | 4888 | 4761 | 4689 | 4573 | 4388 | 4702 |          -5% |        + 3 % |          + 5%|         + 9%  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
| 1  | Jim's | 5156 | 5031 | 5568 | 5505 | 5605 | 5888 | 5761 | 5689 | 5573 | 5388 | 5705 |  bla-bla-bla |  bla-bla-bla |  bla-bla-bla |  bla-bla-bla  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
| 2  | Sam's | 3126 | 3031 | 3268 | 3503 | 3605 | 3888 | 3761 | 3689 | 3573 | 3388 | 3702 |  bla-bla-bla |  bla-bla-bla |  bla-bla-bla |  bla-bla-bla  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How do I reference the data cell for a particular year?
Once I do that, I can perform the calculations.

*Thank you to anyone that takes the time to respond.*

Comment: What are you trying to do that you require a reference to the textbox?

Comment: 'Usually' there is no need to directly reference a cell in a matrix. This may not the the case this time but if you explain what you are trying to achieve there is probably another approach that will be better.

Comment: Actually, now I've looked at your question fully, I can see what you are trying to do. Unfortunately this is not simple in SSRS. There is a PREVIOUS function but that can only reference the previous column so your 1 year change would be fine, but the other calc would be a problem.  In scenarios like this it's probably much easier to calculate this in the query. What database and version are you using? Let me know and I'll come up with a solution

Comment: @DaleBurrell, on the far right of the result grid you'll note that I'm calculating changes over time.

Comment: @AlanSchofield SQL2016 I believe.
This seems like exactly the kind of problem SSRS should have been desinged for.  Sad face.

Comment: You can do it in SSRS but its difficult, much easier in SQL. As you are using SQL 2016 we can take advantage of the LAG functions there. Check back in an hour or so and I'll hopefully have posted a solution by then.

Answer (score 2):

To start with, don't worry about the length of the answer!, I just tend to add a lot of explanation the process is simple enough...

So, I created a similar dataset to your example. My sample data only went up to 2016 so the sample report will only go from 2006-2016. My sample data is country also based.

The following query will produce the data you want, I'll explain it below..

```
SELECT 
       v.*
       , ([Count] - LAG([Count]) OVER(PARTITION By [Location] ORDER BY [Year]))/ LAG([Count]) OVER(PARTITION By [Location] ORDER BY [Year]) as Chg1
       , ([Count] - LAG([Count], 3) OVER(PARTITION By [Location] ORDER BY [Year]))/ LAG([Count], 3) OVER(PARTITION By [Location] ORDER BY [Year]) as Chg3
       , ([Count] - LAG([Count], 5) OVER(PARTITION By [Location] ORDER BY [Year]))/ LAG([Count], 5) OVER(PARTITION By [Location] ORDER BY [Year]) as Chg5
       , ([Count] - LAG([Count], 10) OVER(PARTITION By [Location] ORDER BY [Year]))/ LAG([Count], 10) OVER(PARTITION By [Location] ORDER BY [Year]) as Chg10
    FROM (
          SELECT [Location], [Year] , SUM([Count]) AS [Count]
             FROM soSampleData d
             WHERE [Year] BETWEEN 2006 and 2016
             GROUP BY [Location], [Year]
       ) v
```

So the sub-query (v) simply groups your data by location and year. If your base data is already like this then you can replace the entire sub-query with `FROM myTableName v`.

In the SELECT we are grabbing all the column from v plus the percentage change values. Taking `chg3` as an example, this line reads..

([Count] - [Count from 3 years ago]) / [Count from 3 years ago]) as Chg3, obviously change to suit your calculation requirements! :)

[Count from 3 years ago is achieved by using the LAG function. `LAG([Count], 3) OVER(PARTITION By [Location] ORDER BY [Year])` means get the [Count] column from the 3rd previous row within [Location] when ordered by [Year]. So for Argentina 2015 this will get Argentina 2012.

I suggest you test this out in SSMS before using in your report just to ensure you get the correct results.

**Report**

Create a new report, add a new dataset using the above query. I used the default name "DataSet1" here.

Add a Matrix, set the row group to [Location] , column group to [Year] and data cell to [Count].

next drag the Chg1 thru chg10 fields to the right of the data cell, this will add new columns inside the group.

The design should look something like this...
[image]

Next we want to hide the %chg columns unless its the last instance of the column group (in my case 2016, in your case 2017)

Next, for each of the 4 %change columns, right-Click the grey column header, choose 'column visibility' and set the expression to

```
=Fields![Year].Value <> MAX(Fields![Year].Value, "DataSet1")
```

This basically sets the 'hidden' property to True when the [Year] is not the same as the maximum [year] from the entire dataset called "DataSet1". **Note this is case sensitive**

When we run the report we get the following output. (I added some cell formatting to clean things up, the [count] cell is set to "n0" and the percentage cells format set to "p1")

[image]

Hopefully that's close enough to give you what you want.

Comment: solution I would prefer. Do all calcs in sql server and just use ssrs pivot matrix functionality to render the data. Also your datasource (hopefully a stored proc) also becomes your documentation for these measures.

Comment: Thanks for all the effort.  I'll play with this as well.  I did get it going using the pivot function in a dynamic SQL call and a variable table, within my stored procedure of course.  Took me a couple of hours of digging to get it working, but the above solution may be better.  Problem with the dynamic SQL is there's no way to cache the execution plan.  I did do the 1-, 3-, 5- and 10- year trends in the report.  Doing them there lets who ever comes after me make changes to the report, or re-use the query without having to make changes to both.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to do the calculations in the report.  I did use the pivot function to get my years columns, plugged them into a variable table, and extracted that so the column names are consistent, not changing as the input parameter changes.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you reference with the expression `ReportItems!Textbox0.Value` (the textbox over your textbox1) but in your case you cant reference to specific year because it is in a matrix and all the years are for example in `ReportItems!Textbox0.Value`. But what you can do is to filter it. Something like this:

```
=IIF(ReportItems!Textbox0.Value = "2017", Avg(Fields!Another.Value), Nothing)
```

which would be the same like (which should be used to perform calculations):

```
=IIF(Fields!YourYear.Value = "2017", Avg(Fields!Another.Value), Nothing)
```

Comment: Thanks, let me play with this.

Comment: I could use the report parameter to find the year, so that's part of what I did.